# Drop From One list and Take in other list

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list,

```
list = Table[{n}, {n, 1, 5}]
(*list = {{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}}*)
```

and I want to remove all values from this list that are greater than 3, so that I get

```
newlist = {{1}, {2}, {3}}
```

But the other values should be saved in another list called the drop list to this below as shown

```
droplist = {{4},{5}}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
TakeDrop[sort = Sort[list], LengthWhile[sort, First[#] < 4 &]]
```

> `{{{1},{2},{3}},{{4},{5}}}`

---

As the reminder of [Pillsy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/531/pillsy)'s answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144812/21532)

```
GatherBy[list, 3 < First[#1] &]
```

> `{{{1}, {2}, {3}}, {{4}, {5}}}`

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) and [`Lookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html) to make sure that the two returned lists are in the order you expect:

```
{newlist, droplist} = 
 Lookup[GroupBy[list, 3 < First[#1] & ], {False, True}, {}];
```

The third argument to `Lookup` makes sure an empty list is returned if there aren't any `True` or `False` elements, instead of a potentially annoying [`Missing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Missing.html) object.

```
newlist
(* {{1}, {2}, {3}} *)

droplist
(* {{4}, {5}} *)
```

Comment: +1 If needed, we could account for one of the lists being empty by adding `{}` as the third _default_ argument to `Lookup`.  This is my favourite answer so far.

Comment: I have simplfied your answer to [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144806/21532).Hope don't mind that.

Comment: @yode the only problem with that simplification is it won't always return the lists in the same order, so you won't always know which is `newlist` and which is `droplist`.

Comment: @WReach good point, and a nice change! edited.

Answer (score 5):

one option might be to use `DeleteCases` and then use `Complement`

```
list = Table[{n}, {n, 1, 5}]
newList = DeleteCases[list, {x_} /; x > 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
droppedList = Complement[list, newList]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is the first part better than `newList = Select[list, First[#] > 3&]`?

Comment: @IgorRivin in Mathematica, the rule of thumb is: there are at least 10 different ways to do same thing. Now which one of these 10 ways is "better" than the other left to the reader to decide and can depend on many things. They can also all be equally "good".

Comment: There could be a major performance difference. In fact, there is none between our two ways (for  al list of length 5000000, your method takes 4.02137 seconds, and mine 4.36038 seconds (both pretty pathetic on modern hardware). By contrast, WReach's method (in the other answer) takes 8.75143 seconds.

Comment: @IgorRivin yes. Performance can always be a deciding factor on which method to use.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way that uses `Query`:

```
{dropList, newList} = list // Query[Select /@ {#, Not@*#}] &[#[[1]] > 3 &];

newList
(* {{1}, {2}, {3}} *)

dropList
(* {{4}, {5}} *)
```

... and another way that uses a double `Reap` to collect values sown from a single `Scan`:

```
Reap[Reap[Scan[Sow[#, #[[1]]>3]&, list], False, (newList=#2)&], True, (dropList=#2)&];
```

Comment: I thought `Query[]` was only supposed to work with `Dataset`?!

Comment: @IgorRivin It is the other way around... `Dataset` has a short form for expressing queries :)

Comment: This is what the documentation says:

`Query[Subscript[operator, 1],Subscript[operator, 2],\[Ellipsis]]`
represents a query that can be applied to a Dataset object, in which the successive Subscript[operator, i] are applied at successively deeper levels.

Comment: There seem to be no non-`Dataset` examples...

Comment: @IgorRivin It also says: _Query can operate on a Dataset object or an arbitrary nested expression consisting of lists and associations_.  In fact, it can operate upon any expression as it is simply an alternate syntax for composing operators -- as it _can be seen as a generalization of Part_.  Virtually none of the examples under `Query` involve `Dataset` (there is one in the last section).

Comment: You are right on the first point, but the "short version" only speaks of datasets. The "basic examples" are ALL on datasets. Maybe you have a different version...

Comment: A dataset is used under the [Dataset documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html), but the [Query documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) uses a simple list of associations.  I belabour this point because I think that _Mathematica_ 10's addition of the query-oriented programming paradigm was a significant advancement.  Nested iterations are often considerably easier to express than in the transformational, functional or imperative paradigms.  It is no accident that `Query` works with arbitrary expressions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57925/discussion-between-wreach-and-igor-rivin).

Answer (score 4):

In:

```
xss = Range[5] // Map[List]
yss = xss // Select[# <= 3 & @@ # &]
zss = Complement[xss, yss]
```

Out:

```
{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}
{{1}, {2}, {3}}
{{4}, {5}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Pick[list, (# > 3) & @@@ list, #] & /@ {False, True}
```

> {{{1}, {2}, {3}}, {{4}, {5}}}

Answer (score 3):

This approach uses `SequenceCases`

```
SequenceCases[list, {{_?(# <= 3 &)} ..} | {{_?(# > 3 &)} ..}]
(* {{{1}, {2}, {3}}, {{4}, {5}}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{newList, dropList} = Through[{#[#[[1]] <= 3 &], #[#[[1]] > 3 &]}[lst]] & @ Select
```

> {{{1}, {2}, {3}}, {{4}, {5}}}

Comment: Note the element should be `#<3&`

Comment: @yode, I've taken it into consideration now )))